# read only text from url using java

Tags: java

I have been trying to execute this program, but it shows error saying that `urlconnectionreader` cannot be resolved. I'm new to programming. Can someone help me with this?

This is my code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadTextFromUrl {
    public static String getText(String url) throws Exception {
        URL website = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            response.append(inputLine);

        in.close();

        return response.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // enter code here
        String content = URLConnectionReader.getText(args[0]);
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats because the name of your class is `ReadTextFromUrl` and NOT `URLConnectionReader` !

Comment: thank you....I'm a begginner

Comment: First check response using any third party too; like postman

Comment: change `throws` to `try-catch` and move `in.close(); to finally like if(in!=null) in.close();`

Answer (score 1):

There are Many Libraries to read text from URL, 
You can Try jsoup library to read or extract only text.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class ReadTextFromURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String text = Jsoup.connect("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741265/read-only-text-from-url-using-java").get().text();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to study more is objects.you must know that the classes are the blueprints.you cant use a saw blueprint to saw a tree.you need the saw itself.and by creating a object from that class you will have the saw.so when you have the saw in your hands you can saw the tree.making an object from a class works exactly the same.and using the ways(methods) to saw the tree with the actual saw is like using the methods of the class.

lets think you have a class named Saw and it has a method named sawTheTree.

```
public class Saw {
        public void sawTheTree {
         // do the sawing
          }
            }
```

its the blueprint by now.to use this saw and the method you need this :

```
Saw saw = new Saw();
```

now you have the saw in your hands.lets go and saw the tree.for this you need this code in your main method or where ever you feel the need of sawing the tree.

```
saw.sawTheTree();
```

now the the saw will saw the tree for you.

P.S: in your code you have declared the `getText` method static so you don't need the object creation part.if you are asking why look again at static statement description.but to use a non static method from a class you need to create the object.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the class name should be **URLConnectionReader** or you can change the the calling function via your class name .

```
 String content = ReadTextFromUrl.getText(args[0]);
```